# What is the technological problem that cryptocurrency solves? How does overcoming that technological problem help in the real world?

Tags: cryptocurrency, money-supply

I have read a lot about cryptocurrency and am yet to find a good explanation of why the technology does or even might someday provide an improvement over the current monetary system.

So, what is the technological problem that cryptocurrency solves? How does overcoming that technological problem help in the real world?

Please offer answers that don't already have known solutions. For example:

- Inflation already has a good solution - a responsible monetary policy that controls the money supply.
- Problems with international transfers are (in my view) solved by modern services like [Wise](https://wise.com/nz/).

Comment: just FYI there's actually a cryptocurrency question site, in this SE network. you may wish to ask there.

Comment: *"a responsible monetary policy"* Now, I am a person that trusts government fairly much, and I have experienced no reason myself to change that situation; however - even I can see that governments running the monetary policy is a billy goat minding its own sack of oats. This responsibleness is a unicorn, it sounds beautiful, it is possible to imagine being in existence, but finding it has proven hard.

Answer (score 5):

If you earn your money by selling drugs online or hacking computer systems for ransom money, cryptocurrency is a safer (but not 100 percent secure) way to get paid than other alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer describes how bitcoin solves the technological problem of trustless payment.  The real world applications are when this trust is absent.  There are two main situations where this trust is missing:

1. Where payment processors do not trust the individual.  For various reasons some people are unable to access payment cards. For such people cryptocurrency may be the only way to make remote payments.
2. Where the individual does not trust the payment processor, in particular does not trust the payment processor to keep their details private.  Generally to use payment processor systems you are required to identify yourself, and they will on request provide this information to state level organisations.  If one is involved in fields of commerce not sanctioned by the state this can be a problem, and cryptocurrency use is a solution.

It is worth noting that bitcoin has features that make it sub optimal for these purposes, and other cryptocurrencies may be more suitable.  But bitcoin was the first and still works for many people.

Comment: But how does cryptocurrency provide a better solution to either of those problems than a more secure/private payment service (e.g. PayPal on steroids) that doesn't have the vast, environmentally damaging overhead of mining?  And WRT #1, if people are unable to access cards, how do they access the electronic infrastructure needed for cryptocurrency?

Comment: @jamesqf Bitcoins advantage over a more secure/private payment service (e.g. PayPal on steroids) is that it exists.  If you have some sort of money you can get bitcoin with cash or direct bank transfer.  Otherwise some "field of commerce not sanctioned by the state" may help.

Comment: My point is that if there really was a demand for such a service, one would think that some enterprising person would implement it.  But instead we have BitCoin and other cryptocurrencies, which seem driven by the possibility of becoming rich via mining &c, not through any basic usefulness.

Comment: Unless I’m really misreading this, your answer basically says ‘Bitcoin gets people around “know your customer” laws,’ which isn’t really accurate (in the US KYC is required at places like Coinbase and other US crypto exchanges) and presents KYC laws as some weird hurdle for access to financial services, which is a stretch.

Comment: @jamesqf People use it, and find it useful.  Why no one has come up with a better alternative would be a good question.

Comment: @quid A big part of it is avoiding KYC laws.  Localbitcoin has no KYC requirement, and even if you buy them in an identifiable manner you can make them non-identifiable, by converting to/from monero for example.

Comment: @Dave: How many people actually use it, though?  I mean as an ordinary way of paying for things, or being paid, rather than buying or accepting some as a speculation?  Compare Dutch people who bought tulip bulbs as a speculation, rather than simply wanting some flowers in their garden.

Comment: @jamesqf I do not know, but it is definitely some (another good question?)  To go back to your "more secure/private payment service" that used to be Swiss banks, before the Americans got them to open their books?  They were never an ordinary way of paying for things, but no one claims they had no utility.  I bet they had higher transactions fees.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the technological problem that cryptocurrency solves?

According to the abstract of [Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) by Satoshi Nakamoto:

> **A purely peer-to-peer version of electronic cash would allow online payments to be sent directly from one party to another without going through a financial institution.** Digital signatures provide part of the solution, but the main benefits are lost if a trusted third party is still required to prevent double-spending. **We propose a solution to the double-spending problem using a peer-to-peer network.** The network timestamps transactions by hashing them into an ongoing chain of hash-based proof-of-work, forming a record that cannot be changed without redoing the proof-of-work. The longest chain not only serves as proof of the sequence of events witnessed, but proof that it came from the largest pool of CPU power. As long as a majority of CPU power is controlled by nodes that are not cooperating to attack the network, they'll  generate the longest chain and outpace attackers. The network itself requires minimal structure. Messages are broadcast on a best effort basis, and   nodes can leave and rejoin the network at will, accepting the longest proof-of-work chain as proof of what happened while they were gone.

Bitcoin implemented a novel solution ([blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain)) to the [double-spending problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-spending) of electronic cash without needing a trusted third-party.

Comment: This problem, as you say, has been solved by using a central trusted third party (e.g. Visa) that can verify whether a token has been spent. BTC still uses third parties (the network) for verification. How does using a network of third parties for verification help in the real world versus a single trusted third party?

Comment: @kennyB My guess is that a single trusted third party will be more discriminating than a network of third parties that one does not need to trust. For example, some people have no access to global payment systems (which happens to rely on trusted third parties), so Bitcoin may be attractive to those people.

Comment: @kennyB Although Bitcoin is interesting from an academic point of view, I am less than convinced about its real world uses. I consider myself biased. I believe I have answered your first question ("What is the technological problem that cryptocurrency solves?"). You may be able to get good answers about the real world implications on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com (if such questions are on-topic there).

Comment: "Bitcoin implemented a novel solution" if course, it utterly fails to work as a "retail" currency, since it is incredibly slow and incredibly expensive.

Comment: @Fattie which is 100% better than anything that existed before it - since there wasn't anything. Might as well complain that assembly language doesn't have classes.

Comment: @user253751  I wasn't complaining.  And, I've often pointed out that assembler does not have classes!  :)

Answer (score 0):

> "Inflation already has a good solution - a responsible monetary policy that controls the money supply."

But this is not solvable *by an individual*. Some believe that central authorities are not solving this, so they desire an alternative way to solve it that doesn't depend on a central authority.

> "Problems with international transfers are (in my view) solved by modern services like Wise."

Wise may not support all of the countries where you may want to send money, and as a centralized service it may not give you the autonomy or privacy you would like.

Other issues cryptocurrency is claimed to solve:

- Privacy and anonymity (but not traceability) - Some individuals want to be able to conduct business without disclosing to 3rd parties the nature of that business
- Autonomy - Some people want full control of their money so that they cannot be 'shut-off' as may be the case with centralized systems.

Comment: Bitcoin replaces inflation with deflation, which is worse.